# keep the same value of if statement in a function

Tags: r

I am a beginner at R. I am trying to u create a function with an if.

```
a=function(l){
    if((l==0) || (l==1)){probab=c(prob_cor= round(runif(1, IQ - VAR, IQ + VAR),4),
                      prob_i= round(runif(1,0.20 - VAR , 0.20 + VAR),4)) else probab}
    > l
       [,1]
  [1,]    0
  [2,]    2
  [3,]    3
  [4,]    4
  [5,]    5
  [6,]    6
  [7,]    7
  [8,]    8
  [9,]    1
 [10,]    2

    apply(l,2,a)
```

in this function, my first l=0. and I will get a "probab" value. for the second l, the "if statement" will be wrong, and what I want to keep the same "probab" value previously generated (when l=0) but I never get the same value. Basically, I want to change my probs only when l= 0 or 1 otherwise keep the previously generated value.  what should I do?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
#if 0 or 1 is not at the beginning of l then you might need to uncomment below line
#probab <- NULL
a <- function(l){
  if ((l==0) || (l==1)){
    probab <<- c(prob_cor= round(runif(1, IQ - VAR, IQ + VAR),4),
                 prob_i= round(runif(1,0.20 - VAR , 0.20 + VAR),4))
    return(probab)
  }
  else return(probab)
}

l <- matrix(c(0,2:8,1:2))
apply(l,1,a)
```

Comment: I tried the code you suggested. But here is the same problem again:
> a(0)
prob_cor   prob_i 
  0.7890   0.2099 
> a(2)
Error in a(2) : object 'probab' not found. Still, it does not keep the value " probab" so when the if is false it could not find any probab.

Comment: If `IQ` & `VAR` is defined (e.g. `IQ <- 5; VAR <- 1`) before the code I suggested above then there shouldn't be any issue. Please run `rm(list = ls())` first and then execute my code. (In case of issue provide the exact error message along with the code you tried)

Comment: you were right, I had another mistake smth in my code. your solution solved my question.Thank you a lot